# Sql Server Management Studio - Dynamic New Query Template

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

In Sql Server Management Studio (2008), I want the new query window to be opened with two lines at the top, commented out by default, like below:

```
-- <ServerName>
-- <DatabaseName>
```

The strings between angel brackets must be dynamic, must be set by the values of current connection details.

How can I do it?

Comment: There is no native possibility in SSMS, but I can include it into TODO list for my add-in. I like your proposal: parameterized new query template.

Answer (score 3):

[While you can customize the default contents of the New Query Window by modifying the `SQLFile.sql` file located in your SSMS installation directory](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AmitBansal/sql-server-bi/19/sql-server-management-studio-tip-get-a-customized-new-query-window), values in this file can't be automatically populated with results from the server.

However, as a work-around, you can modify this file to populate the New Query Window with a query that will print out the desired results when ran, that can then be copied and pasted into the open query window.

```
PRINT '-- <' + @@SERVERNAME + '>'
PRINT '-- <' + DB_NAME() + '>'
```